# The distribution function of active Brownian process

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have a problem with the derivation of the distribution function of the stationary state using the system`s propagator as it has been mentioned in equation number 14.

[image]

Basically, we know that the state of any quantum mechanical system evolves using a propagator and if we integrate the state multiplied by its adjoint we will achieve the probability. Here, the derived equation for the distribution function of the system is a little bit complicated to figure out how it has been achieved using the prior equations. I would be so thankful if any one can lend me a hand on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has very little to do with quantum mechanics, the only link is with the similarity of the mathematical formulas up to a Wick rotation (imaginary time).

Intuitively, $\theta$ performs a random walk on the periodic interval $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ (it’s an angle). You can therefore guess that the stationary distribution of $\theta$ is uniform:
$$
dp_{ss}=\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}
$$

You can directly check that it is a stationary solution of the master equation:
$$
\partial_t p(\theta,t)=D\partial_\theta^2p(\theta,t)
$$

You can also deduce it from formula (14). Remember that an angle is defined up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$, so the true conditional distribution is:
$$
p(\theta,t|\theta’)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}e^{-\frac{(\theta-\theta’+2\pi n)^2}{4Dt}}
$$
and by sending $t\to \infty$ you find $dp\to dp_{ss}$. From the previous expression, it is not obvious. One way to get it is by the Poisson summation formula (in fact the condition probability is a Jacobi theta function).

Once you have the distribution of $\theta$ you can get the one for $f$ by change of variables:
$$
f= A\cos\theta
$$
so (derivative of $arccos$):
$$
dp_{ss}=\frac{df}{\pi\sqrt{A^2-f^2}}
$$

Btw, another perhaps simpler method is to look at the propagator of $x$, or even better, of $h=f+ig=Ae^{i\theta}$ with $h=A\sin\theta$. Indeed, the process is gaussian so you can solve it directly.

Hope this helps.